# Facebook application iframe problem

Tags: iframe, facebook

I created an iframe facebook application with a canvas page. I have defined in this application a **page tab** (iframe) and added the page in a facebook fan page. A new tab is correctly created in the fan page. But the content is only displayed when the user is logged in facebook (if not, it's white content). The application is displaying a simple html static page and does not require any authentication.

Furthermore, the application can be accessed correctly when the user is not logged into facebook (direct access, not from the fan page containing the application tab).

**Does anyone have an idea why the users which are not logged in, don't see the content of the tab in the fan page?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that has been already reported to Facebook Developers.
See here : http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15166

So i am afraid you just have to wait until it get fixed..